# Eureka server and UnknownHostException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have installed an Eureka server and have registered a service called pricing-service.
The  Eureka dashboard shows
**UP pricing-service:4ac78ca47bdbebb5fec98345c6232af0**
under status.

Now I have a completely separate Spring boot web service which calls (through a WebClient instance) the pricing-service as http://pricing-service but I get **"reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (pricing-service)"**
exception.

So the Controller can't find the pricing-service by hostname.Further, how is the controller aware of the Eureka server in order to get to pricing-service? Shouldn't there be a reference to it in the application.properties of the web service? I couldn't find anything around the web.

Comment: What have you done to integrate the eureka client into your app? What versions are you using? Can you show your configuration?

Comment: Eureka server application.properties : spring.application.name=eureka-server 
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=ON
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=ON

Comment: pricing-service: 
spring.application.name=pricing-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true

Comment: pricing-service: server.port=8762 or server.port=${PORT:0} don't make a difference

Comment: THe most intriguing part is that how does the separate web service and controller find out about the Eureka server? It has no reference to it or I am missing something fundamental here

Comment: @microwth, please update your question with the above configurations to make it compact and better understandable. Remove the above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I have a completely separate Spring boot web service which calls (through a WebClient instance) the pricing-service as http://pricing-service

1. This *separate* service (the `WebClient` Service) of yours must also register itself with `Eureka Server`.
2. By default, `webclient` is not aware of having to use `load-balancer` to make calls to other `eureka instances`.

Here is one of the ways to enable such a `WebClient` bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfig {

 @Bean
 WebClient webClient(LoadBalancerClient lbClient) {
    return WebClient.builder()
             .filter(new LoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction(lbClient))
             .build();
    }

}
```

Then, you can use this `webClient` bean to make calls as:

```java
@Component
public class YourClient {

 @Autowired
 WebClient webClient;

 public Mono<ResponseDto> makeCall() {

    return webClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://pricing-service/")
            // <-- change your body and subscribe to result
}
```

**Note:** Initializing a `Bean` of `WebClient` can be explored further [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/295).

Comment: "This separate service (the WebClient Service) of yours must also register itself with Eureka Server." You mean register to the Eureka server like the pricing-service i.e : spring.application.name=webclient-service eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=localhost:8761/eureka eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=localhost:8761/eureka eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true –

Comment: also use @EnableEurekaClient ?

Comment: thanks to your help I've managed to do it!Thanks very much!

Comment: @microwth Yes, you got it. Your service where you're using `webClient` to make call to other service (`pricing-service`) must also be a `DiscoveryClient`, i.e., annotated with `@EnableEurekaClient` and `eureka` properties set in `application.properties`. That's how it'll query the registry (`Eureka Server`) for instances based on service-name.

Answer (score 3):

WebClient doesn't know anything about Eureka out of the box. You need to use @LoadBalancerClient and @LoadBalanced to wire it up through the load balancer. See the docs here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue that WebClient was not working with `@LoadBalanced` for me when I created a bean that returned WebClient. You have to create a bean for `WebClient.Builder` instead of just `WebClient`, otherwise the `@LoadBalanced` annotation is not working properly.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution for me